# c++ best way to use for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, iteration, stdvector

I have this question that runs in my mind...
I have a std::vector to iterate:
which is the best way (**the faster**) to iterate?

here is the code using an iterator:

```
// using the iterator
for( std::vector <myClass*>::iterator it = myObject.begin( ); it != myObject.end( ); it++ )
{
    (*it)->someFunction( );
}
```

and here is 'normal' mode...

```
// normal loop
for( int i = 0; i < myObject.Size( ); i++ )
{
    myObject[i]->someFunction( );
}
```

thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Probably doesn't make any visible difference. What do your benchmarks show on your specific environment?

Comment: cache the end iterator and the vector size.

Comment: Use C++0x or boost foreach. You probably won't see any impact on execution speed but reading the code will be more readable (IMO).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

None of the two will be any faster really, because on most implementations a `vector<T>::iterator` is just a typedef for `T*` and `size` is cached.

But doing `++it` instead of `it++` is a good habit. The latter involves creating a temporary.

```
for(std::vector <myClass*>::iterator it = myObject.begin( );
                           it != myObject.end( );
                           ++it)
                           ^^^^
```

On other containers such as `map`, `list` etc. with nontrivial iterators the difference between postincrement and preincrement might become noticable.

Comment: thanks, First I've not seen the code.. but in fact what's the difference doing preincrement?

Comment: if the iterator resolves to a builtin type then nothing. also if you have a good compiler then probably nothing.

Comment: @ghiboz: The preincrement implementations change the iterator itself and return `*this`. Postincrement is equivalent to `this_type tmp(*this); ++(*this); return tmp;` So, a temporary is created and a copy is made

Comment: No, postincrement is `this_type tmp(this); ++(this); return tmp;` since `this` is the iterator, which is a pointer. Most compilers will inline the code, then optimize out the `return` when they see the result is being discarded, then optimize out the `this_type tmp(this);` because it is no longer used, resulting in `++i` and `i++` doing the same thing. This optimization might only happen for iterators that are actually primitive types, such as `std::vector` iterators, so it's a good habit to get into even though you won't see a difference in this one case.

Comment: @Mike: No, `this` isn't the iterator. This is a pointer to the `iterator` if iterator is an object of class-type, as it is, say, for a map or a list. So, I don't follow your logic

Comment: Yeah, that was a botch. Omit the first sentence, replace `this` with  `*this` in the second, and replace `i` with `it` and it'll make more sense. The main point is that if an iterator is implemented as a primitive type, then you can expect pre-increment (`++it`) and post-increment (`it++`) to compile to the same code unless the optimizer is disabled.

Answer (score 5):

If you really care, you can find out: Just make a single source file with one function with that loop and look at the optimized assembly:

```
g++ -O2 -S -o ver1.s ver1.cpp
g++ -O2 -S -o ver2.s ver2.cpp
```

You can directly see the differences! I bet there are none.

That said, you should use the iterator pattern because it's idomatic, generic C++ and it gets you in the right mood -- plus, it works in far more general cases than just vectors! Write it like this:

```
typedef std::vector<MyClass*> myVec;
for (myVec::const_iterator it = v.begin(), end = v.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
  const MyClass & x = **it;
  /* ... */
}
```

In case you're curious, a vector iterator is most likely just going to be a native, raw pointer, so there's really nothing to fear in terms of efficiency, and a lot to be enjoyed from the self-explanatory, algorithmic style!

PS If you have C++0x, say it like this:

```
for (auto it = v.cbegin(), end = v.cend(); it != end; ++it)

// or

for (const MyClass * & i : v)
```

Comment: Totally agree. Plus if you are using C++0x, you will fall in love with auto keyword - you don't even have to typedef all the time to have readable code.

Comment: @gwiazdorrr: Good point, I'll add a C++0x version! Also we have range-based loops there :-)

Comment: Has anyone actually implemented the `for (const MyClass * & i : v)` form yet? The stuff I've read is a little old but says not.

Answer (score 1):

The first code will decompose into incrementing a pointer.  The second one will increment an index, and index into the array.  The first one can use slightly smaller instructions (and thus potentially be faster) assuming the compiler doesn't optimize the second into the first already.  But it will be a trivial difference.

Iterators should be preferred, however, not because of speed but because you can then easily move the code to iterate any standard C++ container, not just `vector`.

However, you've got a few things to improve.

- Don't use `it++`, but `++it`.  This can be very important in C++ because iterators can end up doing a little more work in post-increment which won't be optimized out as if the type were an `int`.
- Don't constantly call `end()` or `size()`.  For some iterator types and collections this might not be optimized out and can be very sub-optimal.
- Use `vector::size_type` when you need an index into a `vector`.  `int` is not guaranteed to be big enough, while `size_type` was made specifically for that.

So, the better ways to write these are:

```
// using the iterator
for(std::vector <myClass*>::iterator it = myObject.begin( ), end = myObject.end(); it != end; ++it)
{
    (*it)->someFunction( );
}

// normal loop
for(std::vector <myClass*>::size_type i = 0, size = myObject.size(); i < size; ++i)
{
    myObject[i]->someFunction( );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
int s = vec.size();
for(int i=0;i<s;i++)
{
    T &o = vec[i];
    ...
}
```

This loop has the following advantages over other approaches:

1. it always looks the same (unlike the hacks that change from i++ to ++i)
2. it's relatively short to write (compared to the iterator version)
3. the int indexes are useful in your public interface (unlike iterators)
4. it still always looks the same (unlike stdlib algorithms, where you need documentation to remember the parameters)
5. it's very old and thus widely used. (originally comes from book "The C programming language" aka K&R)
6. It doesn't give warnings on most compilers (unlike the loop that was used in the question)

It does have some disadvantages too:

1. some newer programmers doesn't like it because they think C ways are too old
2. in a const function, you might need to change it slightly to `const T &o = vec[i];` or change the data member mutable
3. type `T` changes depending on the use

Comment: "it always looks the same (unlike the hacks that change from i++ to ++i)" -- As stated in the post above, performing a postfix increment there is not good practice since theoretically the operator called is returning a temporary reflecting the state of i before increment, and you simply don't need it there. Nontrivial postfix increments (on more complex containers for ex.) can also eat up more clockcycles.

Comment: err, the temporary stuff is just bullshit. Compilers will just optimize it away and there is no change in performance. But it's actually very bad advice because it makes half the loops use i++ (because it's the established practise coming from K&R) and the rest ++i, making it more difficult to keep all the loops look the same. It's way more important that every loop looks the same, than do some low level optimizations with temporaries.

Comment: I never said that an optimizer will most probably do exactly what you want anyway but postfix increment, in the exact context of the loop, *theoretically* does more than you want whereas the prefix one does it exactly right. That aside if you use ++i instead of i++ consistently that's just fine as well. And in larger projects with many authors there certainly are bigger issues in terms of style consistency than ++i versus i++, to say the least. Also custom containers may actually value the difference between either operator.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  for (int i = 3; i > 0; i--) {
    cout << i << "\n";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

source https://mockstacks.com/Cpp_For_Loop