# How to handle and iterate through this list?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this type of list:

```
std::list<MyClass*>*
```

I want to iterate through this list and I also want to call the methods of MyClass, I want to do something like this:

```
std::list<MyClass*>* elements;

for (?)
{
    std:: cout << elements[i]->Membermethod(); << std::endl;
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c++ best way to use for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6706059/c-best-way-to-use-for-loop)

Comment: take a look at: https://onlinegdb.com/-aa6C_r85

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::list<MyClass*>* elements;
for (auto it = elements->begin(); it != elements->end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << (*it)->Membermethod() << std::endl;
}
```

note that its highly recommend not to put raw pointers in collections, use std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr

Much cleaner (also in c++11) is a 'ranged for'

```
for (auto pel : *elements) {
    std::cout << (*pel)->Membermethod() << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: Both of these code snippets require C++11, unless you meant to write `std::list<MyClass*>::iterator` instead of `auto` in the first one

Comment: @UnholySheep the question is tagged c++11

Comment: @Taekahn I'm referring to the "in later versions of C++ you can do" part of the answer. Both solutions require the same C++ standard

Comment: @Taekahn, you should take a look at this, but not aggressively this time: https://onlinegdb.com/6fV73rXiW
What he wants is not a primitive array.

Comment: aha I had not realized that ranged for was that old, ty

Comment: @OrkhanAliyev if you think a simple quip is aggressive, I have some bad news about your future. As I stated previously, the point was to illustrate, not be 100% perfect. I’m on a phone.

Comment: @pm100, you should mention that `elements` is nullptr at first.

Comment: @pm100 Thank you very much for your solutions, I tried the first one, but I missed the Membermethod() return value, but it is my mistake (in addition the compiler did not throw any warning).

Your second solution work for me this way:

`for (auto item : *elements)
{
    std::cout << (*item).Membermethod() << std::endl;
}`

Comment: @BusinessMan strongly , strongly recommend using shared_ptr or unique_ptr (strongly, did I say strongly)

Comment: @BusinessMan `(*item).Membermethod()` should be `item->Membermethod()`. And, while `auto item` is fine when the `vector` holds raw pointers, if you ever change the `vector` to hold smart pointers instead, you should use `(const) auto &item` or better `auto &&item` instead (will also work for raw pointers).

Comment: @RemyLebeau You are right, thank you, I tried it.